# Find summation and count only if they are EQUAL in Excel

Tags: excel, count

In EXCEL sheet I have 1728 rows and 2 columns (`L` and `O`). I am doing addition of these 2 columns in column `P`. Further I want to count the occurrence in this column if addition is EQUAL to 2 or 4 or 6 or 8 BUT condition here is that The COUNT should be such that BOTH the columns `L` and `O` are EQUAL and Their addition is either 2 or 4 or 6 or 8.

This means that only the columns in L and O with values "1+1" , "2+2", "3+3", "4+4" should be counted. The addition of "1+3", "4+2" should not be counted.

```
=COUNTIF(P:P,4)
```

does not work.

```
    L     O     P     M
===========================
    1     1     2     1 (NO OF 2'S)
    2     2     4     1 (NO OF 4'S)
    3     3     6     1 (NO OF 6'S)
    1     3     4*    NO TO BE COUNTED
    4     4     8     1 (NO OF 8'S)
    2     4     6*    NOT TO BE COUNTED
    4     2     6*
```

AS SEEN ABOVE RESULT OF COUNTING IS STORED IN M. Let me know the formula

Comment: See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) good question topic and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: i have added the formula for what i have done..check the description of question.

Comment: Thanks Forward Ed..

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(L29=M29,SUMPRODUCT(--($L$29:$L$35=$M$29:$M$35)*(L29=$L$29:$L$35)),"Not Counted")
```

My data started in row 29 so you will need to adjust the references.  It counts the entire table in 1 shot.  So if you added a row to the bottom that had 1 and 1 and 2, the results in column M in your first row would become 2 and the same for the row you just added.

Answer (score 0):

Will this formula help...?

```
=IF(AND(A1=B1,OR(SUM(A1,B1)=2,SUM(A1,B1)=4,SUM(A1,B1)=6,SUM(A1,B1)=8)),SUM(A1,B1),"NOT TO BE COUNTED")
```

Just drag the formula till you have data. You will need to adjust the references.

Here is the reference data.

[image]